# Sphinx realtime updates for attributes

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I am trying to implement a sphinx search server on a website. The website is to be used for internal tracking.

The database defines a status, which I have configured to be a attribute in sphinx. I need this to be updated in real time without any lag. I also want to use disk indexes so regular updates to the index can be done quite easily and I avoid the SphinxQL.

I have found that this is possible via the UpdateAttribute method of the sphinx API. 
What I want to know is if it is possible to call the UpdateAttribute() from a MySQL trigger? I thought I could have a php script that takes the required inputs in a get request and then updates the index. Please suggest possible ways to implement as I haven't yet found anything that works.

If you have any other way of implementing the search so that I get attributes updated in real time then please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: are you using SphinxSE storage engine? Or a standalone server daemon? Im not sure Id recommend a trigger for either case, but if its a daemon then definitely not.  Even if you used PHP and Sphinx daemon, you're looking at a lag of maybe 30ms. Can you explain why this is unacceptable?

Comment: @carpii Not using SphinxSE. The database is in MySQL using InnoDB. "Im not sure Id recommend a trigger for either case, but if its a daemon then definitely not." - didn't get this. Could you please specify the two cases that you are referring to and the advice with respect to each. I wanted to implement this by calling a php script via sys_exec and curl. The script then does the work of updating the index with the sphinxAPI. Why will the lag be so high? Is there another method of doing the same thing? Open to all suggestions so please have a go at the last question.thnx

Comment: SphinxSE is a MySQL storage engine, where you can query Sphinx directly from MySQL. The alternative is to run the searchd deamon, and query/update Sphinx using an API (PHP, or whatever). It sounds like you;re using the daemon/API method.  The lag of 30ms I was referring to, was assuming you are running Sphinx daemon on a separate server, its subjective, but a reasonable estimate as to how quickly you could update Sphinx after issuing a MySQL update from your PHP.

Comment: I should probably point out that Im not 100% sure its even possible to update Attributes from SphinxSE. But using API, then UpdateAttribute() is the way to go.

Comment: There is another compromise proposal to not have to install Gearman. Not as good, but it may be enough for many. Shown in [http://fragmentosdeprogramacion.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/mantener-actualizados-los-indices-del.html](http://fragmentosdeprogramacion.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/mantener-actualizados-los-indices-del.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UpdateAttribute is the right method.

IMO it is possible to call this method in MySQL trigger using MySQL user defined function. But, I don't think it is good solution, because such function will be very complex and will slow down mysql updates very much.

A much better solution was posted to the sphinxforums. Its using gearman and the present UDFs that exists for it. (technically writing UDF for the sphinx C API is better but this is just easier) see [here](http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=9823).

Comment: Do you mean that it is possible to call UpdateAttribute() directly from the MySQL? How? Since this function is defined in the PHP API for Sphinx I thought it must have to be called from PHP itself. Can you please expand some more on why it would slow down updates? Thanks

Comment: To use UpdateAttribute directly from MySQL you have to use C API. 

Such function will slow down mysql update queries, because it have to connect to sphinx on each update.

Comment: How do I use the C API? And more importantly how does MySQL use it? AFAIK I will need some UDFs for this since sphinx doesn't have its own UDFs

Comment: A much better solution was posted to the sphinxforums. Its using gearman and the present UDFs that exists for it. (technically writing UDF for the sphinx C API is better but this is just easier) see [here](http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=9823)